Apache 2.4 keeps writing in old log file despite logrotate restart
I am using logrotate on RHEL 9 to rotate access logs of an Apache 2.4 (actually IBM HTTP Server) running as root.
The config I use is a series of the following for each access.log file:
<HTTPServer path>/logs/access.log {
    compress
    dateext
    maxage 60
    rotate 99
    daily
    notifempty
    missingok
    postrotate
         <HTTPServer path>/bin/apachectl restart
         /bin/sleep 10|/bin/true
    endscript
}

However, after the rotation (and the postrotate action) the apache process seems to keep writing to the previous file <HTTPServer path>/logs/access-<prev data>.log (the file inode to be honest), which now is deleted from compression action.
The apache process starts writing to the original file <HTTPServer path>/logs/access.log again only when running <HTTPServer path>/bin/apachectl restart from cli.
I have tried all possible combinations (e.g. delaycompress, group all access files in one config and set sharedscripts etc) on how to resolve this, except copytruncate, which I would like to avoid.

As which user is the logrotate cron-job being triggered? As which user do you run the apachectl restart manually?

Everything is running as root. It seems we have an http config issue so the httpd cannot be restarted correctly only when restarted as postrotate action, not from shell
